# Adicionar foto em planilha excel a partir de pasta local

Tags: imagem, microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho uma planilha em Excel com uma lista de pessoas. Para cada pessoa tenho um código. Em uma pasta local eu tenho fotos destas pessoas e o nome do arquivo das fotos é o código da pessoa.

Tem alguma fórmula ou algo assim que eu possa usar para fazer o Excel ir na pasta buscar a foto de cada uma das pessoas automaticamente? Preciso que as fotos apareçam na linha com os dados daquela pessoa.

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Até onde eu sei não há uma fórmula pronta que faça isso. Mas você tem algumas opções.

### Opção 1

A opção mais simples e que não envolve VBA (usa apenas fórmulas e funções existentes no Excel "básico") requer que você adicione manualmente cada uma das imagens em uma planilha qualquer, defina nomes para cada célula contendo as imagens e use esses nomes para fazer a referência indiretamente. Eu não vou reproduzir essa solução aqui porque não foi o que você solicitou diretamente e porque ela tem o principal problema de que você precisa adicionar as imagens manualmente e construir uma fórmula enorme que é nada menos do que uma sequência encadeada de chamadas para `SE`, o que começa a se tornar impraticável se você tiver mais do que uma dezena de códigos. Mas você pode achar essa solução [neste site de "Dicas do Excel"](http://excel.tips.net/T003128_Displaying_Images_based_on_a_Result.html) (em inglês).

### Opção 2

A segunda alternativa, que é a solução que eu proponho, requer o uso de VBA e que a sua planilha seja habilitada para a execução de macros. Mas ela é muito melhor porque adiciona as imagens automaticamente a partir do disco, como você deseja, e garante que as imagens estão sempre posicionadas corretamente na célula também de forma automática.

Para isso, abra a janela de desenvolvedor (usando o atalho Alt+F11 ou [adicionando a opção "Desenvolvedor" na fita de botões](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx)) e adicione um novo módulo. Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, digite o código da seguinte função no módulo criado:

```
Public Function getImage(ByVal sCode As String) As String

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim oImage As Shape

    Set oCell = Application.Caller ' Célula onde a função foi chamada
    Set oSheet = oCell.Parent      ' Planilha que chamou a função

    ' Procura por uma imagem existente identificada pelo código (que precisa ser único!)
    Set oImage = Nothing
    For i = 1 To oSheet.Shapes.Count
        If oSheet.Shapes(i).Name = sCode Then
            Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i


    ' Se ainda não existir uma imagem com o código, carrega do arquivo e cria-a.
    ' A imagem já é posicionada na exata posição da célula onde a função foi chamada.
    If oImage Is Nothing Then
        sFile = "c:\temp\sopt\" & sCode & ".jpg"
        Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(sFile, msoCTrue, msoCTrue, oCell.Left, oCell.Top, oCell.Width, oCell.Height)
        oImage.Name = sCode

    ' Caso contrário, se a imagem já existir, garante que ela se posiciona e cabe exatamente dentro da célula
    ' (apenas para o caso do usuário ter movido ou redimensionado manualmente a imagem sem querer)
    Else
        With oImage
            .Left = oCell.Left
            .Top = oCell.Top
            .Width = oCell.Width
            .Height = oCell.Height
        End With
    End If

    ' Retorna nada para a célula (afinal, esta é somente uma função de auxílio)
    getImage = ""

End Function
```

> Não se esqueça de salvar a planilha com a extensão .xlsm (Pasta de
>   Trabalho Habilitada para Macro do Excel).

Então, nas células do Excel onde você deseja que as imagens sejam exibidas, use a fórmula:

```
=getImage(<CÓDIGO>)
```

Por exemplo, suponha que na célula B4 você tenha o código de uma imagem. Para automaticamente adicionar a imagem desse código na célula C4, adicione nela a fórmula `=getImage(B4)`. Eis uma ilustração do resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código da função está comentado para ajudar no entendimento, mas basicamente ele funciona da seguinte forma:

1. Ela recebe como parâmetro o código, que pode vir de qualquer origem (pode ser um valor fixo ou pode vir de uma célula, como no exemplo acima).
2. Com base nesse código, e na aba (planilha) de chamada (note que isso é diferente da planilha ativa! Essa função pode estar sendo executada em segundo plano pelo Excel por outra aba que não a ativa!), a função carrega a imagem apenas se ela ainda não existir (evitando que a mesma imagem seja carregada múltiplas vezes e sobrecarregue o seu arquivo Excel).
3. Com base na célula de chamada (a célula onde a função foi chamada), a função também ajusta a posição da imagem e o seu tamanho, como forma de *simular* que a imagem esteja dentro da célula. Observe que o Excel não permite ter valores de célula que são imagens, por isso essa "simulação".
4. Por fim, a função devolve (retorna) uma string vazia. Isso é necessário pois ela é usada como uma "fórmula" no Excel, apesar de fazer uma manipulação indireta ao conteúdo da célula.

Note que essa função é capaz de garantir que a imagem é redimensionada automaticamente conforme você ajusta o tamanho das células, mas para isso a função precisa ser reavaliada! Por motivos de desempenho, o Excel não reexecuta toda fórmula sempre que você redimensiona as células. Por isso, se você as redimensionar, precisa chamar novamente as funções - uma a uma, editando a célula e pressionando ENTER, ou (muito melhor), simplesmente solicitando ao Excel a reavaliação de todas as fórmulas com o atalho <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

### Edição

O código que eu fiz não puxa qualquer imagem, ele literalmente gera erro (e o Excel para o programa) se não encontrar a imagem. Você deve ter feito algo diferente do que eu sugeri.

De todas as formas, ao invés de não exibir nada, talvez seja melhor você ter uma imagem específica para indicar fotos inexistentes, para que o usuário perceba que não foi um erro qualquer do sistema. Use algo como uma imagem de usuário (como [esta daqui](http://iconmonstr.com/picture-4/)). O código é simples de alterar. Basta indicar para o VBA continuar executando no caso de erro (note a linha `On Error Resume Next` adicionada logo no começo da função) e verificar se o objeto imagem retornado é vazio (isto é, se é igual a `Nothing`). Se for, você força o carregamento da imagem padrão que vai utilizar. Exemplo de código alterado:

```
Public Function getImage(ByVal sCode As String) As String

    On Error Resume Next ' Indica que no caso de erros de carregamento de imagem deve continuar executando a partir da próxima linha

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim oImage As Shape

    Set oCell = Application.Caller ' Célula onde a função foi chamada
    Set oSheet = oCell.Parent      ' Planilha que chamou a função

    ' Procura por uma imagem existente identificada pelo código (que precisa ser único!)
    Set oImage = Nothing
    For i = 1 To oSheet.Shapes.Count
        If oSheet.Shapes(i).Name = sCode Then
            Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i


    ' Se ainda não existir uma imagem com o código, carrega do arquivo e cria-a.
    ' A imagem já é posicionada na exata posição da célula onde a função foi chamada.
    If oImage Is Nothing Then
        sFile = "c:\temp\sopt\" & sCode & ".jpg"
        Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(sFile, msoCTrue, msoCTrue, oCell.Left, oCell.Top, oCell.Width, oCell.Height)

        If oImage Is Nothing Then ' Verifica se falhou o carregamento da imagem. Se falhou, adiciona a imagem genérica (com nome fixo)
            Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\temp\sopt\inexistente.jpg", msoCTrue, msoCTrue, oCell.Left, oCell.Top, oCell.Width, oCell.Height)
        End If

        oImage.Name = sCode

    ' Caso contrário, se a imagem já existir, garante que ela se posiciona e cabe exatamente dentro da célula
    ' (apenas para o caso do usuário ter movido ou redimensionado manualmente a imagem sem querer)
    Else
        With oImage
            .Left = oCell.Left
            .Top = oCell.Top
            .Width = oCell.Width
            .Height = oCell.Height
        End With
    End If

    ' Retorna nada para a célula (afinal, esta é somente uma função de auxílio)
    getImage = ""

End Function
```

Resultado que ele gera (com a imagem padrão chamada de "inexistente.jpg" e mantida no mesmo diretório das demais - note que eu literalmente apaguei as imagens da águia e da raposa para elas gerarem o "erro"):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Observação: esse código é bem simples e serve de exemplo. Note que ele
>   verifica se uma imagem *com o código* já existe e por isso não a
>   recarrega se já existir (para melhorar o desempenho). Isso significa
>   que se um usuário não tinha uma imagem e aí a planilha carregou a
>   genérica, se ele depois criar uma imagem a planilha não vai atualizar
>   adequadamente. Você vai precisar manualmente excluir a imagem do Excel
>   e atualizar para que a imagem correta apareça.

Por fim, note que se mesmo assim você quiser não exibir nada caso a imagem não exista, basta manter a primeira linha de código (o `on Error Resume Next`), verificar que ocorreu o erro e *não fazer nada*. Nesse caso você nem teria que se preocupar com o comentário do parágrafo acima, pois se eventualmente a imagem aparecer o código vai se ajustar sozinho. Só que simplesmente não mostrar nada para o usuário é uma péssima usabilidade, pois pode causar confusão (ele vai notar que "nada aconteceu", mas não vai necessariamente compreender que a imagem dele está faltando).

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema com a segunda opção Luiz, muito obrigado =)
Deixa eu te perguntar uma coisa. Não entendo muito de VBA então não consegui modificar o código para resolver uma questão. Tem alguns funcionário que não possuem foto. Neste caso ao invés de não puxar foto alguma ele puxa a primeira foto que foi encontrada na lista. Você saberia dizer como faço para não aparecer foto alguma caso não haja foto na pasta corresponde ao código procurado?

Comment: Ok. Fiz uma edição rápida pra ilustrar essa questão, pois a sua "nova dúvida" era bem simples e ainda bastante relacionada (e, por sorte, eu ainda não havia apagado o teste que eu fiz aqui). Mas observe, por favor, que este site *não é um fórum*. Se você tiver outras dúvidas de VBA no futuro, você é bem vindo a abrir outras perguntas, ok?

Comment: Solucionou completamente meu problema. Na próxima lembrarei de abrir uma nova pergunta. Novamente agradeço pela ajuda e pela atenção Luiz.