# Adicionar foto em excel a partir de pasta local

Tags: imagem, microsoft-excel, vba

Olá,

Segui os passos todos os passos aqui - [Adicionar foto em planilha excel a partir de pasta local](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151434/adicionar-foto-em-planilha-excel-a-partir-de-pasta-local)
E tudo funcionou bem.

Mas queria redimensionar as imagens e alinha-las ao centro da célula - horizontal e vertical.

Como não sabia como fazer, editei assim: `oCell.Width / 1.2, oCell.Height / 1.2`

A imagem ficou com o tamanho que queria em relação à célula, mas fica sempre alinhada em cima à esquerda. 
Como faço agora para alinhar a imagem ao centro da célula?

Comment: E já agora como funciona se tiver 2 ou mais folhas no ficheiro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você diz que "editou" eu estou supondo que você alterou esse trecho de código:

```
With oImage
    .Left = oCell.Left
    .Top = oCell.Top
    .Width = oCell.Width
    .Height = oCell.Height
End With
```

Para isso:

```
With oImage
    .Left = oCell.Left
    .Top = oCell.Top
    .Width = oCell.Width / 1.2
    .Height = oCell.Height / 1.2
End With
```

Ou seja, na prática você reduziu o tamanho da imagem. Assim, para centralizar a imagem na célula (sem se preocupar com quanto de fator foi aplicado) o jeito mais fácil é você adicionar às coordenadas do topo (`Left` e `Top`) a metade do tamanho da célula e diminuir a metade do tamanho da imagem (que precisa então ser calculado *antes*, conforme o fator que você está aplicando). Tente assim então:

```
factor = 1.2 ' Separei em uma variável só pra deixar claro que você pode
             ' mudar sem precisar mexer nas duas linhas finais.
With oImage
    .Width = oCell.Width / factor
    .Height = oCell.Height / factor
    .Left = oCell.Left + oCell.Width / 2 - .Width / 2
    .Top = oCell.Top + oCell.Height / 2 - .Height / 2
End With
```

Comment: Oi @GuilhermeNascimento. Obrigado! Pra falar a verdade, eu não testei (Ricardo, algum feedback a respeito?). Mas em princípio está correto sim, porque a ideia é descontar a metade da própria altura da imagem (por isso o `.Height` sozinho). Caso contrário, do jeito que vc sugere, você soma e subtrai o mesmo valor, não é? rs :)

Comment: Nossa é que faz tempo que eu não trabalho com VB, eu queria dizer isso `oImage.Height`, mas somente agora me dei conta do `With`, obrigado, o +1 está garantido ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Relaxa. Foi bom ter perguntado, porque aí confirma o entendimento. :)

Comment: Perfeito. Resultou na perfeição. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu, Ricardo. Nesse caso, por favor considere marcar a resposta como aceita. Saiba mais aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers