# Macro VBA para inserção de imagens automaticamente com base numa coluna de códigos

Tags: imagem, microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma planilha, na qual possui uma coluna com o código das fotos e na outra coluna ao lado com espaços para inserir as imagens. Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de elaborar um macro, em que ele reconheça o código preenchido ao lado e busque numa determinada pasta a foto relacionada a este código.

Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No intuito de apenas complementar, há a possibilidade de acrescentar na fórmula a correção de 2 restrições? Seguinte, quando há o código da foto na planilha (ex: 1532) porém na pasta não há foto com esse código, tem como ele pular a linha em que está descrito esse código e continuar inserindo fotos para as próximas? E a outra restrição seria pra ele pôr foto somente onde está vazio e pular aquelas que já tem foto.

Comment: Deduzo que este código da imagem seria o nome dela, né?! Então o código poderia usar um caminho e extensão de arquivo padrão, por exemplo `"C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\" & CodigoFoto & ".jpg"`. Dedução correta?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Adicionar foto em planilha excel a partir de pasta local](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151434/adicionar-foto-em-planilha-excel-a-partir-de-pasta-local)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi certo, vc tem esta tabela numa planilha (no VBA considerei que estivesse na no intervalo **A2:B6**) e o que vc chama de código se refere ao nome do arquivo da imagem, sem sua extensão e pasta localizada.

Com essas deduções sugiro o seguinte código:

```
Sub Teste()

'Definir intervalo onde estão os códigos das imagens
    Dim TodosCod, Cod As Range
        Set TodosCod = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A9")

'Definir variáveis para o procedimento de inserção de fotos
    Dim Pasta, Ext, TxtCod As String
    Dim Fig As Shape
    Dim FigJaExist As Boolean
        Pasta = "C:\Users\TashRiser\Desktop\"
        Ext = ".jpg"

'Inserir a imagem baseado no código da imagem
    For Each Cod In TodosCod
        TxtCod = Cod.Value
        FigJaExist = False

'Checar a existência do arquivo
        If Not Dir(Pasta & TxtCod & Ext) = "" Then

'Checar se há alguma foto na célula de destino
            For Each Fig In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                If Fig.TopLeftCell.Address = Cod.Offset(0, 1).Address Then FigJaExist = True
                Next Fig

'Se não houver foto na célula, inserir o arquivo
            If FigJaExist = False Then
                With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Pasta & TxtCod & Ext)
                    .Left = Cod.Offset(0, 1).Left
                    .Top = Cod.Offset(0, 1).Top
                '...caso queira determinar a largura e altura da imagem
                    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                    .ShapeRange.Width = 100
                    .ShapeRange.Height = 100
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next Cod

End Sub
```

Comment: Agradeço o retorno amigo. Uma dúvida, preciso gerar um botão, ou largo o código e atualizo ctrl+alt+Shift+F9?

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi!!! Vc quer saber como gerar um botão por código ou como colocar um botão para rodar esse código? E q o Ctrl+Alt+F9 tem haver?

Comment: Consegui!!!! Cara, sem palavras, deu certinho, até a função de dimensionar na célula. Muito obrigado pela ajuda cara, admiro muito o empenho do pessoal que ajuda aqui.

Comment: Que bom que deu tudo certo! Não esqueça de dar aquele *check* verdinho para a resposta certa, e se possível dar votos, assim vc incentiva os respondentes e contribui para o crescimento da comunidade!

Comment: Pode deixar, amigo! Agora, no intuito de apenas complementar, há a possibilidade de acrescentar 2 correções de restrições? Seguinte, quando há o código da foto na planilha (ex: 1532) porém na pasta não há foto com esse código, tem como ele pular a linha em que está descrito esse código e continuar inserindo fotos para as próximas? E a outra restrição seria pra ele pôr foto somente onde está vazio e pular aquelas que já tem foto. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Adaptei o código para atender a estas duas restrições. Sugiro que vc edite sua pergunta original e insira esta questão, para partilhar com a comunidade. Se ficar apenas no comentário, a visibilidade é menor!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!!! Muito obrigado. Já editei a pergunta conforme sugerido.