# MACRO para inserir imagem com relação a lista suspensa

Tags: vba, macro

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou com uma dúvida que não sei se é ou não leviana:

Tenho um campo (o retangulo grande) da qual quero inserir uma imagem dentro dele, conforme a lista suspensa selecionada.

Por exemplo: Quando eu selecionar na lista suspensa (L11) "Ceu2", eu quero que no retangulo apareça a imagem do "Ceu2" localizada em Q6. Quando selecionar Ceu, a mesma coisa, porém para a imagem em Q5.

Porém, no mesmo retangulo, quando a pessoa selecionar através da célula L3 a 2ª Lista suspensa, com as opções, deixe de aparecer as imagens do céu e apareça o qual ela escolher, seja o "oculos" ou o "trem".

Só até ai já seria ótimo. Eu estava tentando fazer isso usando as funções ÍNDICE e CORRESP, porém não atingia o limite de caracteres da função CORRESP kkk

Se alguém puder dar uma mão até ai.. depois quero que passado X tempo sem uma nova troca de opção da lista suspensa, a imagem que aparecesse no retangulo fosse a do "tema" contido em Q9

Se ficar confuso volto a explicar, mas a princípio era isso mesmo. Obrigado a quem puder dar uma ajuda =)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151434/adicionar-foto-em-planilha-excel-a-partir-de-pasta-local

Answer (score 2):

### Solução sem macro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro daquilo que já construiu o que você precisa fazer é criar um [Nome Definido] com formula e depois vincular com a câmera. Seguem os passos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1. Entre em [Gerenciador de nomes]
2. Em gerenciador de nomes crie um novo item
3. Passos:

```
NAME> cImage
Scope> Workbook
Comment> [branco]
refers to: > =OFFSET($Q$4;MATCH($L$11;$P:$P;0)-1;0)
Botão {OK}
```

Adc. um componente de camera, para ativar:

1. File > Options
2. Siga os passos de 1 a 5. Opção 6 deve abrir para ti.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A partir daqui é só selecionar a célula que esta a imagem. No seu caso a $Q$5. e clicar na câmera. Note que a imagem vai respeitar o tamanho do range/célula. Logo tente adicionar. imagens do tamanho que pretende usar e redimensionar a célula e a imagem do mesmo tamanho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quando selecionar a câmera que nada mais é do que um quadrado pontilhado, mude no travessão de formula por `=cImage`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o evento cbxListaSuspensa_change para que, cada nova mudança na sua lista uma macro fosse excutada e a partir desta execução a imagem fosse altera para o caminho da imagem que está contida na lista suspensa.

```
Sub cbxListaSuspensa_change()
Dim caminho As String
'Valor que está na lista suspensa
caminho = cbxListaSuspensa.Value
'Setar a imagem que deve ser colocada no espaço
sheet1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(caminho)
End Sub
```

[image: Cenário criado para o código]

Comment: Olá Vinícios, não sei se entendi muito bem. Mas no seu exemplo a imagem iria aparecer conforme a seleção da lista suspensa, certo? Porém eu tenho + de 1 lista suspensa, e quero que conforme eu vá selecionando as opções da lista, a imagem que aparecerá no quadro se altere também

Comment: É só usar um segundo evento como cbxListaSuspensa2_change. Desta forma, quando o segundo ter seu valor alterado a macro será executada.

Comment: Realmente não estou conseguindo nem mesmo executar o seu exemplo, mas continuarei tentando

Comment: O caminho não seria algo como: `caminho = ThisWorkbooh.Path & cbxListaSuspensa.Value` ou `caminho = "C:/Fotos" & cbxListaSuspensa.Value`