# Inserir uma imagem na planilha do Excel com VBA porém sem o vínculo com a imagem original

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou criando um gerador de tabelas no Excel e preciso inserir várias imagens que estão em uma determinada pasta.

Faço essa inserção pelo seguinte código:

```
altura = 3
On Error Resume Next
For L = 1 To ultimalinha 
    If Guia.Cells(L, 1).Value <> "" Then
  'DEFINE O NOME DA IMAGEM
        arquivo_img = Replace(Guia.Cells(L, 2).Value, "/", "")
'INSERE A IMAGEM E DEFINE O NOME
        Guia.Pictures.Insert(caminho_img & arquivo_img & ".jpg").Name = arquivo_img
'POSICIONA CORRETAMENTE A IMAGEM E REDIMENSIONA
        With Guia.Pictures(arquivo_img)
            .ShapeRange.Height = 89
            .Top = altura
            .Left = (Guia.Columns("A:A").Width) / 2 - .ShapeRange.Width / 2
        End With
    End If
'Guia.Shapes.Range(Array(arquivo_img)).ShapeRange.Item(1).Hyperlink.Delete
altura = Guia.Cells(L, 1).Height + altura

Next L
```

Tentei utilizar o método `Guia.Shapes.Range(Array(arquivo_img)).ShapeRange.Item(1).Hyperlink.Delete` para quebrar o vínculo da imagem porém sem sucesso.

O código que insere a imagem na planilha eu já tenho, porém, preciso de algum procedimento ou comando que faça esta imagem não ter nenhum vinculo externo, que se caso eu mova a pasta ou até envie a planilha por e-mail, as imagens continuem na planilha.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Adicionar foto em planilha excel a partir de pasta local](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151434/adicionar-foto-em-planilha-excel-a-partir-de-pasta-local)

Comment: Essa pergunta não é útil para o meu problema pois este método continua com o vínculo externo. Mas obrigado pela sugestão!

Comment: Você utiliza o `Insert` que deixa vínculo externo, a resposta do link acima utiliza o `Shapes.AddPicture` que não deixa vínculo externo...

Comment: Funcionou!! Obrigado!